# php preg_match numbers 2000 - 2999

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to write an if statement that continues if $var equals any number 2000 - 2999 inc.

```
if ( preg_match( '/^20.*/', $var) ) continue;
```

This seems to work, but would that also match on 20123456 or 20001-1234-2345 etc ?

How do I limit it to just 2000 - 2999 inclusive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way with regex:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^2[0-9]{3}$/', $var) ) continue;
```

`[0-9]` matches any digit character. `{3}` says match it exactly 3 times. So it would match `000`, `001`, `120`, `999`, etc... `$` matches the end of the string.

See this [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/iB3yG5/2) for more information. (Use the unit tests on the left to make sure the function is matching what you're looking for)

Comment: 2100 Do I need to say something else :)

Comment: this wont match 2999?

Comment: I missed 2000-2999. I thought it was 2000 to 2099. Updated answer

Comment: @Tom I posted the regex101 link, and it has some unit test functionality to show you what it matches/doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Why via `preg_match`?
You can use classic `if`:

```
if ($var >= 2000 && $var <= 2999) continue;
```

Comment: I'd not thought of doing it like that. Much simple to read back in a few weeks time :)

Comment: Yes, exactly:-) If isn't concrete reason for comparing via `preg_match`, it's better to have code simply effective and easy readable.